# A retraction of a residually finite group is separable

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that if $G$ is residually finite, then a retraction $R$ of $G$ satisfies the condition that the intersection of all finite indexed subgroup of $G$ containing $R$ Is equal to $R$ itself, i.e.
$$
\bigcap_{ R \leq H \leq G,\ |G:H| finite} H =R?$$

Comment: I think you should say what you mean by a retraction of $G$.

Comment: A retract of $G$ means a subgroup that is the image of an endomorphism $p$ of $G$ such that $p^2=p$. Equivalently, it's a subgroup $H$ that is part of a semidirect decomposition $G=H\ltimes N$.

Comment: Well yes I know, but I was hoping that the OP would tell me.

Comment: Yes, what @YCor said is exactly what I meant by a retraction.

Answer (score 0):

Write $G=R\ltimes N$. Let $(M_i)$ be a family of normal subgroups of finite index with finite intersection. Define $N_i=M_i\cap N$: this is a normal subgroup of $G$, contained with finite index in $N$. So $N_iH=HN_i$ is a subgroup. It follows that $\bigcap HN_i=H$ ad $HN_i$ has finite index in $G$.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why we can write the group as a semi direct product? Thank you.

Comment: @MeggyLee what is the definition of retract you start with?

Comment: The image of an endomorphism $p$ such that $p^2=p$.

Comment: Then $G=\mathrm{Im}(p)\ltimes \mathrm{Ker}(p)$.